# Automatically sync updates to DBML across multiple .NET projects?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Every time we update the database and DBML of one project we usually must update them across the rest of them as well.

Can anyone think of a clever way of auto-syncing/updating a DBML file across multiple .NET projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easiest way is to have that DBML as part of its own project, and then have your other projects depend on the DLL out put from the project that's holding the DBML file.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines. Do you have any information on the 'have other projects depend on the DLL'? Do I link it into the compilation somehow, how will it get updated? Or, will I just manually deploy a new DLL to each project basically?

Comment: Yeah, there're a number of ways.  You can manually deploy the DLL or you could use nuget on your own server.  If they're all concurrently being developed, the easiest method might be to just include teh DBML project in each apps' solution, and then add a reference to that project.